# in chrome, html5 audio element will be mute unexpectedly

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio

I have followed some events and attributes:
All the events can't be fired at all, like progress canplay, play and so on.

The attributes seems right:

```
muted: false, 
loop: true,
ended: false,
autoplay:true,
error: null.
networkState: 2(The user agent is actively trying to download data.)
readyState: 4(HAVE_FUTURE_DATA)
seekable.end(0): 56.81632614135742
```

Some timeranges:

```
played.length: 0, 
buffered.length: 1,
buffered.end(0): 56.81632614135742,
```

And another strange thing: I open another site with a HTML5 sounds game, it's also mute.
Now the only way to solve the problem is closing the chrome and to open it again.
My chrome is ver.16

Did you meet the same problem ? Dose this a problem of chrome ?

Comment: If you supplied some code we could actually have a proper look for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a solution, sorry, but rather a confirmation that I know what you're talking about ;-)
I think it's a Bug in Chrome. Last Week or so there was an update. I have a rails app, wich plays a short sound file via Audio(). Before the update it played smoothly, after the update, though no code regarding this feature was changed it plays most sound (randomly) as if you'd click the pause button in the middle of the recording and then play again, very fast. I have no pause button though.
In Safari, OmniWeb, Firefox there's no such problem with the very same codebase.
I think we'll read some more of such observations in the near future.

Comment: Thank you..And I have found that it's a bug of chrome indeed..Here the link:[link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=audio&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=107933)